# Trying to autofit row height in excel VBA when target cell value is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to autofit the height of certain rows within a worksheet whenever the value of certain cell changes. I've tried the following code which isn't giving me results.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F3")) Is Nothing Then
    
        Me.Rows("6").AutoFit
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the value changing due to formula recalculation? Or due to a user-initiated change?

Comment: Why do you want to autofit row 6 when cell F3 (so row 3) is changing?

Comment: Works for me if the value of F3 is changed manually.

Comment: Yes, changing due to formula recalculation. If I change values manually in F3 and then press enter row height is getting changed but not automatically when formula recalcualtes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AutoFit Row When a Formula Changes a Cell Value

- Adjust `Worksheet_Name`.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Public Const Worksheet_Name As String = "Sheet1"
Private Const Cell_Address As String = "F3"
Private Const AutoFit_Row As Long = 6
Public Old_Value As Variant

Sub changeValue(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws.Range(Cell_Address).Value <> Old_Value Then
        ws.Rows(AutoFit_Row).AutoFit
        writeNewValue ws
    End If
End Sub

Sub writeNewValue(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    Old_Value = ws.Range(Cell_Address).Value
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    changeValue Me
End Sub
```

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error Resume Next
    writeNewValue Worksheets(Worksheet_Name)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

### Simplified (Inaccurate)

- It will run on the first recalculation, even if the value has not changed.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Old_Value As Variant

Sub changeValue(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws.Range("F3").Value <> Old_Value Then
        ws.Rows(6).AutoFit
        Old_Value = ws.Range("F3").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    changeValue Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This works really fine.